# How to differentiate between two Sublime windows

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I am running two Sublime windows at the same time. In one window I'm getting code to update the other one. Both are using the same color pattern, so I am confused between them.

My question is, is there a way to distinguish in between the windows? Making color-scheme different, or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a very simple [plugin](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html) and [key binding](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html). First, select **`Tools -> Developer -> New Plugin...`** and replace the contents with the following:

```py
import sublime_plugin


class ChangeWindowColorSchemeCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        for view in self.window.views():
            view.settings().set("color_scheme", 
                                "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Cobalt.tmTheme")
```

You should change `"Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Cobalt.tmTheme"` to whichever color scheme you'd like to use in the window. Save the file as `Packages/User/change_window_color_scheme.py` - if you just go to **`File -> Save`** it should automagically open to `Packages/User`.

Next, create a new key binding by selecting **`Preferences -> Key Bindings-User`** and adding the following if the file is empty:

```js
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+c", "s"], "command": "change_window_color_scheme" }
]
```

If you already have some custom key bindings, add the following on the line following the opening square bracket `[`:

```js
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+c", "s"], "command": "change_window_color_scheme" },
```

Save the file, and everything should be all set. Select the window you'd like to change the color scheme for, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> - meaning you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, release them, and hit <kbd>S</kbd>. You can change the key binding if you wish, of course.